# Laravel 5.8.* Auth mail error from local server: swift_transportexception (554)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

if I run my project in **Laravel 5.8.*** from my local PC via MAMP Pro using the normal **`php artisan make:auth`** command and the correct SMTP configuration, I cannot send a confirmation mail from my local PC with Mamp via my external mail server.

This error code always appears then:

> Swift_TransportException
>
> Expected response code 354 but got code "554", with message "554 5.5.1 Error:  no valid recipients

Laravel storage/day.log:

> [2019-03-11 14:25:20] local.ERROR: Expected response code 354 but got
>   code "554", with message "554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients "
>   {"userId":9,"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code:
>   554): Expected response code 354 but got code \"554\", with message
>   \"554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients \" at
>   /Users/*****/Developer/Laravel-Project/Laravel-System/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:457)
>   [stacktrace]

However, this appears ONLY on my laptop with MAMP on my web server everything works fine.

In my .env file it looks like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.my-external-mail-server.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=alias@my-domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

and in my cofig/mail.php:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mail.my-external-mail-server.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => 'alias@my-domain.com', 'name' => 'my-domain.com'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('alias@my-domain.com'),
'password' => env('********'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'markdown' => ['theme' => 'default',
'paths' => [resource_path('/views/vendor/mail'),],],
```

These settings also work great with the normal `make:auth` command from Laravel on my own server with my own mail server but the above error message comes up whenever I test it on my local PC with MAMP.

Does anyone know what it is? Is it only possible to send mails with an active SSL connection? How can I avoid this error?

Comment: run php artisan cache:clear

Comment: @SaurabhMistry I've tried this command several times but the error message kept coming back.

Answer (score 1):

**I just found the answer myself!!!**

> NOTICE: Check before if the mail in connection with the configuration is sent via the SMTP server from another location. For example another server or another local development environment.

Anyone who has the same error should check these entries.

Change the **PORT** and the **ENCRYPTION** to:

```
MAIL_PORT=465
#AND
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Then execute the following commands in the Project root folder:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```